# Why aren't Tweets tagged with #?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Wouldn't be it better to tag keywords (with prepended symbol #) in published Tweets?

http://twitter.com/stackenglish

some examples:

> "A lost case, that is." http://ur.ly/CNPR #grammar
>   "An RPG" or "A RPG"? http://ur.ly/CMRa #pronunciation
>   When referring to a previously sent text, would you say 'I text you about that' or 'I texted you about that' ? http://ur.ly/COhY #usage
>   "I'm having" - an illness? http://ur.ly/COfk #grammar
>   What is the origin of "earthling"? http://ur.ly/CMuD #usage
>   Should I write"a tweet" or "a twit", "to tweet" or "to twit"? http://ur.ly/CMIL #usage
>   Word for "someone who does the same job as me" http://ur.ly/CKgA #wordchoice

Why aren't #tagging used in Tweets?

Comment: Well, #tags are used... you are quoting them yourself in the question!

Comment: @Don, it seems to me that @FX_ commented before Jeff's editions.

Comment: @Dori, thanks. I seem to have some kind of optical filter blocking me to see Jeff's activity in StackExchange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, it's turning the most popular of the given question's tags into a hashtag (as seen [here](http://twitter.com/StackEnglish)).

If SO wanted to add another hashtag, what criteria would they use? That is, how would an automated system know what to emphasize?

Comment: There's also the max character length to keep in mind.